# Bootstrap Nuget Package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nuget

Anyone recommending a Nuget package for Twitter Bootstrap for an ASP.NET MVC 4 application?  I'm not too crazy about what's out there at nuget.org.  What are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have downloaded it from the [official website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) directly into the ASP.NET MVC project. It's a bit more work but at least I have full control and I know what I'm getting.

There's also [Kickstrap](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/), which I haven't tested yet but seems promising.

Note: It's necessary to customize the path to the images folder from "../img/" to "/", otherwise CSS bundles in ASP.NET MVC 4 don't load images as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing the same.

Comment: I also customized the path to the images folder from "../img/<path>" to "/<path>", otherwise CSS bundles in ASP.NET MVC 4 don't load images as expected.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to know which one to use, is to look at the package content.

Check this github repository by sirkirby: https://github.com/sirkirby/twitter-bootstrap-nuget

- You will find "**Twitter.Bootstrap**", and this is the most downloaded Nuget Package for bootstrap.. you just find the normal **basic bootstrap *css/js/image* files** and the package direct it to Content folder.
  (details here in the repository > twitter.Bootstrap/Twitter.Bootstrap.nuspec).

installing "**Twitter.Bootstrap**" = downloading the bootstrap files from the official website and adding them to your web app.

- Also you will find "**Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC**", it will just add couple of lines to the "BundleConfig.cs" file so that Upon installation it adds bundling and minification support for easy integration into your shared layouts and views. and this package depends on the previous package.

installing "**Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC**" = downloading the bootstrap files from the official website and adding them to your web app + adding references for bundling and minification.

- If you need to have Bootstrap with .LESS Files instead of .CSS, install "**Twitter.Bootstrap.Less**" package.

--

*you can check all other NuGet Packages the same way we just did.*

Answer (score 2):

Try to install these two projects.

Scaffolding with form validation should also work out of the box with these two.

[MVC 4 TwitterBootstrap Starter Layout Page (Razor)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/268d0b05-6ba5-4793-9a10-7d9d2a478881)

[BootstrapScaffoldMVCTemplates](https://github.com/carlosblanco/BootstrapScaffoldMVCTemplates)

Answer (score 0):

There is another package you might find useful: **[TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc).**

The article contains links to the repository, and an intro video.

This library has nothing to do with the scaffolding or bundles. It's a library of html helpers that mostly make it easier to write form related stuff.